# Why isn't the value of the list changing even after I modify its value inside the function?

Tags: python, string, list, mutable

We know that lists in Python are mutable objects. However, the following code does not change the value of the list whose value is being modified inside a function.

```
def change(l):
    l=l[2:5]
    return()
l=[1,3,4,5,2,10]
change(l)
print (l)
```

I expected an output [4,5,2] but it's showing the results [1,3,4,5,2,10].

Comment: `l=l[2:5]` replaces the local reference to point to a new list. It doesn't modify the original list at all

Comment: The `l` inside your function is a different name than the `l` outside. All you are doing is reassigning the name to a new reference. You could do something like `l[:]=l[2:5]` instead. Or return a new list `return l[2:5]` and reassign outside the function: `l = change(l)`

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as UnhloySheep and Mark Meyer states, changing the code from

```
l = l[2:5]
```

to

```
l[:] = l[2:5]
```

should fix your issue.
You complete code should be:

```
def change(l):
   l[:]=l[2:5]
return()

l=[1,3,4,5,2,10]
change(l)
print (l)
```

this print as your answer.

> [4, 5, 2]

Answer (score 0):

As you mutate the list inside a function, you will need to return the updated list like:

```
def change(l):
    l=l[2:5]
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't mutating the list; you are just changing the value of the local variable `l`. Instead, modify the *object* referenced by that variable.

```
def change(lst):
    del lst[5:]  # or lst[5:] = []
    del lst[:2]  # or lst[:2] = []
    # or just l[:] = l[2:5], which I forgot about until reading César Correa's answer


some_list = [1,3,4,5,2,10]
change(some_list)
print (some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def change(l):
   l[:] = l[2:5]
```

The above code will work.

Normal slicing changes the reference of the list after slicing. You can check this by using
`id()` before and after slicing